# Piping raw code from github to ruby not working?

Tags: ruby, curl

I am doing some basic piping of some simple raw code from github to terminal as shown [here](https://quickleft.com/blog/command-line-tutorials-curl/) i.e.

```
curl https://raw.github.com/leachim6/hello-world/master/r/ruby.rb | ruby
```

When I try it, it doesn't produce "Hello World", but instead I just see

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 curl  -sSL  https://raw.github.com/leachim6/hello-world/master/r/ruby.rb | ruby
```

this should work

**Update to explain**

- this URL is redirecting to
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leachim6/hello-world/master/r/ruby.rb`
  so -L option was required to follow the redirection (-L, --location)
  this option will make curl redo the request on the new place
- sS to hide the progress bar and show errors if happened
- to debug curl request you can use -v option which will make you see exactly what is happening

Comment: It works! Any idea why it wasn't working without the `-sSL` option?

Comment: @user5783745: It would be helpful if you could explain what is unclear to you about the documentation of curl. That way, the curl developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems again. In other words: you will be making the world a better place, and who doesn't want that?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I followed [this](https://quickleft.com/blog/command-line-tutorials-curl/) (super basic) tutorial (actually, it was for something completely unrelated). But I came across the idea that you could curl in some code from github (I would have otherwise copy/pasted it).

Comment: -sSL are three options `-s` make it silent (remove the progress bar) `-S` (show errors in silent mode ) `-L` ( which solves the problem ) allow following redirections and the url above was redirecting to another URL you can use -v option to see the logs

Comment: i updated the answer it seems that people were downvoting :D because they didn't understand how it works